# Struct VS Class

Tags: c#, class, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Struct v/s Class in C# - Please explain the behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924054/struct-v-s-class-in-c-please-explain-the-behavior)

I am confused that have seen often that we create custom object by following

```
public class Student
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Class{get;set;}
  public string Section{get;set;}
}
```

and create instant and use its attributes as property for example

```
List<Student> absentUsers = new List<Students>();

Student studenttoadd = new Student();//Object
studenttoadd.Name = "You";
studenttoadd.Class = "PlayGroup";

absentUsers.Add(studenttoadd);
```

and so on

but isn't it true that we can do same with `Struct`?

What is mentioned approach called(example i have given)?

When to Use this approach and when to use struct?

is there any performance /memory allocation difference?

Comment: See the following answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620843/does-it-make-sense-to-define-a-struct-with-a-reference-type-member/5621610#5621610, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456463/protection-level-of-a-struct-field-within-a-class/5456563#5456563

Comment: @Cody: I started to write an answer and realized that 'Struct vs. Class' has been repeated many times.

Comment: It would be a huge mistake to use `struct` here. A common mistake for people from C++ etc, but a mistake.

Comment: so basically when would you prefer struct over this approach